# ZF2: Populating select element in form with date from database

Tags: php, zend-form, zend-framework2

I have a database with a simple one-to-many relationship that looks like this:

```
Tables   Company        Category
Rows     ID             ID
         Name           Name
         Category_ID
```

I have a forms where I can add, edit and delete the company's or category's name, which works fine. Entering the category by ID also works, but is obviously terrible to use. What I want is a simple select element in the form to pick from an existing category.

The code I have to generate the `<select>` is:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'Categorie',
        'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'attributes' => array(
            'options'  => $categories,
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Categorie',
        ),
));
```

From what I could find in the (extremely sparse) ZF2 documentation, I should be using a `Hydrator` to fetch data into the `$categories` variable, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Any sort of example or tips would be well appreciated!

Comment: The answer as well as the following blog post contain valudable information to getting started with ZF2, Forms and Doctrine: http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/07/04/new-zendform-features-explained/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160324000541/http://samminds.com/2012/07/a-blog-application-part-1-working-with-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/)'s a very good article about forms.

My solution is based on this tutorial and it is (almost) working well. I don't know if you use Doctrine for your project or not, but I think it would be a very good idea!

I also heavily use select elements. In the given fieldset, I generate value options for a select with this piece of code:

```
$opt= Registry::get('entityManager')->getRepository('My\Entity\Categories')
                ->getCategoriesForCombobox();
$this->get('category')->setValueOptions($opt);
```

If you (plan to) use Doctrine, you should read about repositories very carefully in the Doctrine documentation. If you use collections in the form, the topic about associations is also a must read.

Comment: Thanks for linking me, just as an info though, the post will be updated soon, because the Registry-Thing really sucks :) Furthermore when working with Doctrine there's easier stuff to use.

Comment: Thanks! Sam: is there going to be major changes to the implementation compared to your current post?